# Парсинг не выходит

Tags: php

Не получается спарсить из html. Получаю пустоту

Текст

```
<tr class="showed">
  <td align="right" width="32">6:10</td>
  <td>
   Комическая фантазия о жизни, любви и смерти знаменитого барона Мюнхгаузена, жившего в XVIII веке и ставшего героем многих веселых книг и преданий, опирается на персонажей и эпизоды знаменитого романа Р. Распе, но по сути является самостоятельным произведением.
          </td>
</tr>
```

Моя попытка

```
preg_match_all('/<tr class="showed">(.*?)</tr>/',$get_m,$showed);
echo $showed[1][0];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/<tr class="showed">(.*?)<\/tr>/s', $get_m, $showed);
```